# Nhibernate QueryOver's SelectList with HasMany property

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have problem building the projection in Nhibernate using the QueryOver's JoinAlias and SelectList for the List property.

I have domain object PageRic which has IList property PageHeaders:

```
    public class PageRic: AuditableLegacy
{
    public virtual string Ric { get; set; }
    public virtual McdDistId McdDistId {get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PageHeader> PageHeaders { get; set; }
    public virtual string Pointer { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Dup { get; set; }
    public virtual int Throttle { get; set; }
}
```

PageHeaders property is mapped as HasMany:

```
        public class PageRicMapping : ClassMap<PageRic>
{
    public PageRicMapping()
    {
        Table("PAGE_RICS");
        Id(x => x.Ric, "RIC").Not.Nullable();

        References(x => x.McdDistId, "MCD_DIST_ID")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.PageHeaders)
            .KeyColumn("RIC")
            .Fetch.Subselect()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Not.LazyLoad();

        Map(x => x.Pointer, "POINTER");
        Map(x => x.Dup, "DUP").Not.Nullable().CustomType<YesNoType>();
        Map(x => x.Throttle, "THROTTLE");
        }
}
```

When I execute this query:

```
            PageRicDTO pageRicDTO = null;
        McdDistId McdDistAlias = null;

        var results = Session.QueryOver<PageRic>()
            .JoinAlias(x => x.McdDistId, () => McdDistAlias)
            .SelectList(list => list
                                    .Select(x => McdDistAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.McdDistId)
                                    .Select(x => McdDistAlias.ShortName).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.McdDistName)
                                    .Select(x => x.Ric).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.Ric)
                                    .Select(x => x.Throttle).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.Throttle)                                        
                                    .Select(x => x.Rowstamps).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.Rowstamps)                                        
                                    .Select(x => x.PageHeaders).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.PageHeaders)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<PageRicDTO>())
            .List<PageRicDTO>();
```

I get IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Here is what I get in the log file:

2012-04-18 15:00:38,823 [CurrentAppDomainHost.ExecuteNodes] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - 
    SELECT
        mcddistali1_.MCD_DIST_ID as y0_,
        mcddistali1_.SHORT_NAME as y1_,
        this_.RIC as y2_,
        this_.THROTTLE as y3_,
        this_.ROWSTAMPS as y4_,
        this_.RIC as y5_ 
    FROM
        PAGE_RICS this_ 
    inner join
        MCD_DIST_IDS mcddistali1_ 
            on this_.MCD_DIST_ID=mcddistali1_.MCD_DIST_ID

2012-04-18 15:00:39,306 [CurrentAppDomainHost.ExecuteNodes] WARN  NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.GetResultColumnOrRow(Object[] row, IResultTransformer resultTransformer, IDataReader rs, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)

When I comment out the   **.Select(x => x.PageHeaders).WithAlias(() => pageRicDTO.PageHeaders)** I get the DTO object.

Can you please help me find the solution for this issue?

Comment: Is PageRic a fully blown entity? or is it a DTO?

Comment: Hi Rippo, PageRic is a fully blown entity. I have another object PageRicDTO which is a DTO object

Comment: Every get anywhere with this?

Comment: I'm having problems with this too after upgrading from NHibernate 2.2 to 3.3.1. Would love to get a resolution to this.

Comment: I know this is old. But any update on this, I have the same issue? @EvgeniyO did you ever figure this out?